# How do I call my function to use it to shorten my code

Tags: php, html, function

How would I use this function in chk_Btn_Sub() in my script, where am I going wrong?

```
<?php
//start my session
session_start();
//calling the function
chk_Btn_Sub();
?>
//displays my form
<form method="post" action="captcha.php">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
        <tr><td>Type The Letters You See Below Into the Box</td></tr>
        <tr><td align="center"><img src="image.php"></td></tr>
        <tr><td align="center"><input type="text" name="image" value="">
        //check if the $error = true
        <?php if (isset($error)): ?>
            <div style="color:red;">error</div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php if (isset($success)):?>
                <div style="color:green;">success</div>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check CAPTCHA">     </td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And this is my function that i am creating to call at the top of my page under session_start() function

```
<?php 
function chk_Btn_Sub(){
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            if (empty($_POST["image"]) || isset($_POST['image']) != $_SESSION['string']){
                $error = true;
            }else{
                $success = true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you `include` the .php file the function is in?

Comment: Not answering your question but `//check if the $error = true <?php if (isset($error)): ?>` it not checking if `$error` is true

Comment: @DickieBoy thats because im checking then $error inside my function. im trying to shorten my code and gain a better understanding about functions in php

Comment: @hermann where do you think im going wrong?

Comment: @code I just fixed a typo in your title. Nothing wrong other than that.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function correctly but you need to remember to `include` the file that the function resides in before you can use it.  For example

```
<?php
//start my session
session_start();
//include the file
include 'path/to/file.php';
//calling the function
chk_Btn_Sub();
?>
```

Comment: that doesnt do anything bro

Comment: @code Do you have error reporting on?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: if i use the function in the same file and put it right at the bottom of my code under the </html> then i am i still able to use the function just as a check before i move my function to a new file to be included in the top of my main script

Comment: yes i have it set to error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", TRUE);

Comment: function chk_Btn_Sub($error, $success) <-what does it mean when i pass those arguments to the function?